# Delete windows os and go back to mac os

Tags: windows, bootcamp

At first I installed windows on my Mac using Bootcamp. Later I discovered I re installed another windows on the previous windows os without going back to mac os to use bootcamp and now no apple trace on this current windows because I didn’t use bootcamp but installed another windows from previous windows. Opt key wouldn’t work for me to go to boot mode because it seems it’s fully on windows and nothing about bootcamp displays on this current windows. I need help to delete this windows and go back to mac.

Comment: Which specific Mac is this? Older Macs don't have the same boot options, but holding down COMMAND-R should boot you into recovery mode and allow you to re-install macOS.

Comment: To expand on Steve Chambers's comment, see https://support.apple.com/HT204904 for detailed instructions on how to boot into recovery mode and reinstall macOS.